# Ampersand To Open File Stopped Working

Tags: command-line

I have a symbolic link to sublime text 2 'subl', so usually I open or create files in the current directory by typing `subl& hw2.py` for example. This would open the file in the editor and allow me to continue using the terminal. However, today it doesn't like that any more and I get the following response:

```
$ subl& hw1.py
[1] 2563
hw1.py: command not found
```

Any idea what's going on here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the binary is called `subl&`? Is quite strange. To do what you are trying to do you should put the ampersand at the end of the command:

```
subl hw1.py &
```

If you don't want that the program exits when you close the terminal, use:

```
nohup subl hw1.py &
```

or

```
subl hw1.py &
disown
```